# How can I set an SSL certificate with React on cPanel Server?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ssl, https, cpanel

I'm a newbie on React.js.

I'm trying to deploy a React.js website to a cPanel Server which doesn't have Node.js support. So I'm using these steps:

1. `npm run-script build`
2. Move `build` folder content to server's `public_html` via `git-ftp`

CPanel has free SSL. I've used it so much times with PHP.

I can access to my website with `http://example.com`. But when I try to access to `https://example.com`, it returns `ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR`.

Here is my *package.json* file:

```
{
  "name": "example",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@material-ui/styles": "^4.10.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "fetch": "^1.1.0",
    "history": "^5.0.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-notifications-component": "^2.4.0",
    "react-owl-carousel2": "^0.3.0",
    "react-router": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "react-toast-notifications": "^2.4.0",
    "uuid": "^8.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [">0.2%", "not dead", "not op_mini all"],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "homepage": "."
}
```

How can I set the HTTPS protocol and make the page work?

Answer (score 0):

you can install it in your **ssl/tls** section on cppanel (and this worked for me)

1. Log in to cp panel
2. Enter Username/Password
3. Go to your Homepage
4. Click SSL/TLS
5. Click Install an SSL Certificate on a Domain -the domain which you want to install on.
6. Type in your domain name
7. Input your Certificate Files
8. hit install
9. reload it.
   -----bang ssl is installed.

**you can use free ssl sites like**

1. HubSpot
2. Let’s Encrypt
3. Comodo
4. Cloudflare...etc

Comment: have you changed your nameserver?

Comment: Ofcourse. I can access to http://example.com. It's something about React